# TiKZ picture does not sit properly in `figure` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, diagrams

This code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\title{Lorem ipsum}
\author{me}
\date{now}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blah blah blah...

\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\spiral#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,1);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,1)}, rotate=90, scale=1/1.6180339887]
      \spiral{#1-1}
    \end{scope}
    \draw [red] (0,0) arc (0:90:1);
  \fi
}

\tikz[scale=2]{\spiral{12}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The golden spiral.}
\label{ref:golden_spiral}

\end{figure}

Sed tortor tellus, &c., &c.

\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: Behold the odd placement of the diagram.]

Obviously what I want is for the diagram to be where that big gap in the text is now. I've used `tikzpicture` in figures before, and it's worked properly, so presumably it's something about *this* diagram that's producing the problem, but I don't see what it is. How can I get that spiral to sit where it belongs?

Edit: [this earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58517/tikz-picture-overlaps-with-text-not-wanted?rq=1) suggests that re-invoking `tikz` is the problem. Is that the issue here? And if so, how should I modify the line `\tikz[scale=2]{\spiral{12}}`? I tried removing it altogether, but that just meant that the diagram didn't appear at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing the definition of `spiral` and its use. Put the definition in preamble. Also, the second `\tikz` is not needed.  Further, there are `&` without `\`. It should be `\&c., \&c.` and add `[htb]` to the options of `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\spiral#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) rectangle ++(-1,1);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-1,1)}, rotate=90, scale=1/1.6180339887]
      \spiral{#1-1}
    \end{scope}
    \draw [red] (0,0) arc (0:90:1);
  \fi
}
\title{Lorem ipsum}
\author{me}
\date{now}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blah blah blah...

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\spiral{12}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The golden spiral.}
\label{ref:golden_spiral}
\end{figure}

Or

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\tikz[scale=2]{\spiral{12}}
\caption{The golden spiral.}
\label{ref:golden_spiral}
\end{figure}

Sed tortor tellus, \&c., \&c.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I have put the title metadata etc in the preamble.

Comment: This works. I notice that the spiral in your screenshot is much larger than in mine. How do you adjust the size of the image?

Comment: @crmdgn hehe, I magnify in sumatrapdf and then take screen shot.

Comment: No I mean it's larger _relative to the text_. Also the `\centering` command doesn't seem to work in my version; the spiral is at the left margin.

EDIT: Strike my last; the `\centering` works. My error. Still curious about image scaling though.

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out.